# OfficeJs SSO getAccessTokenAsync returns error code 3000,Access denied

Tags: active-directory, office-js, amazon-iam

[I have followed all steps but I had some changes due to my unique setup.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs)

I had unique setup where none of the services were hosted on azure so I used aws azure active directory integration.
[I used following tutorial to configure AWS Azure Active directory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/amazon-web-service-tutorial)
[I followed this tutorial to configure sso for my word addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs)

After following tutorial I got this below error

getAccessTokenAsync return

```
result = {
    status: "failed",
    error: {
        code: 7000,
        message: "You don't have sufficient permissions for this action.",
        name: "permission denied",
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it but I do not remember how.